# cocos2d: How to detect which CCLabelTTF was tapped? Showing an AlertView

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch

I have a quiz type of game. One question and 4 possible answers. The answers are dynamically pulled from JSON file from web services. I have 1 question displayed as CCLabelTTF and 4 answers (a, b, c and d) also as CCLabelTTF. Now, I need to show an alert for confirming the answers whichever the user has selected/tapped.
- First question: How can I detect the answers a, b, c and d? I mean which answer the user has touched?
- Second, How can I assigned a unique property to each of these answers? I mean I want to do like this:

```
CCLabelTTF *answerA = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"This will be dynamically set" fontName:@"verdana" fontSize:25];

answerA.tag = @"Here goes the unique Identifier for answerA"; /* Is it okay with tag or is there some more good process? I am thinking to do answerA.tag = 0; 0 for incorrect and 1 for correct answers. */
```

This tag identifier will be used to compare the correct answer and the selected answer like this:

When the user tap "YES" in Alert, the following comparison will occur:

```
 if(answerA.tag == @["movies"][i]@["answer"][i]@["status"]) // @["movies"][i]@["answer"][i]@["status"] will either have 0 or 1.
```

Is there another great solutions for this game? Like what if buttons used instead of text label? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use CCMenu would be better,

```
bool ControlsLayer::init() 
{
    CCTTFLabel *ttflabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"This will be dynamically set" fontName:@"verdana" fontSize:25]
    CCMenuItemLabel *label = [CCMenuItemLabel initWithLabel: ttflabel];

    CCMenu *menu = CCMenu::menuWithItems(label, NULL);
    menu->setPosition(ccp(windowSize.width/2, controlsLabel->getPosition().y - controlsLabel->getContentSize().height));

    this->addChild(menu, 2);

    return true;
}

void ControlsLayer::backButtonAction(CCObject* pSender)
{
}
```

https://github.com/clawoo/AsteroidsCocos2D-x/blob/master/Classes/ControlsLayer.cpp

Comment: there are some dynamic texts that I need to append on the fly as the game advances to next question. So, I thought to use CCLabelTTF. I guess assigning the tag will work though I have not tried it out yet. I am now stuck on the touch/tap part of the game. Do you know any links to know about cctouchbegins with CCLabelTTF or similar functionality? I will also like to try your solution, appreciate it NEO, thanks

Comment: the menu and item can be updated on the fly. you can update text on menu item via ttflabel. i'd suggest to chance scence for advancing to next question to have better effect. CCLabelTTF inherits CCNode, so you could implement like this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437010/how-to-get-objects-to-react-to-touches-in-cocos2d